# vfork return values to parent and child

Tags: c, linux-kernel, fork, system-calls

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
int main()
{
   pid_t pid;
   if((pid=vfork())<0)
    {
            perror("FORK ERROR");
            exit(1);
    }
    if(pid==0)
    {
            printf("[CHILD] child id : %d\n" , pid);
            _exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
            printf("[PARENT] process id : %d\n" , pid);
            exit(1);
    }
```

}

The above program uses vfork to create process.
So , address space is shared between parent and child.
It implies that there is only a single copy of pid variable.
But when i print the pid variable in child it gives 0. The same pid variable in parent gives the process id of the child.
How is this possible if there is only one copy of pid variable.

Comment: Only a single copy of pid is existing.
Printing the address of pid in child and parent is same.
As per vfork documentation also , both parent and child share the same address space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [return value in vfork() system call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347928/return-value-in-vfork-system-call)

Comment: I've removed my answer; the duplicate question explains it much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent returns from vfork() after the child, so pid gets overwritten with the "correct" value.

In kernel source tree , kernel/fork.c

in function do_fork()

```
 do_fork()
 {
 ......
 if (clone_flags & CLONE_VFORK) {
                    p->vfork_done = &vfork;
                    init_completion(&vfork);
                    get_task_struct(p);
            }

            wake_up_new_task(p);

            /* forking complete and child started to run, tell ptracer */
            if (unlikely(trace))
                    ptrace_event(trace, nr);

            if (clone_flags & CLONE_VFORK) {
                    if (!wait_for_vfork_done(p, &vfork))
                            ptrace_event(PTRACE_EVENT_VFORK_DONE, nr);
  .....
     return nr; // pid of the child process.
```

}

you can see that call to **wait_for_vfork_done**.
so the parent is waiting here for vfork to return.
once the child exits , parent resumes from here.
child pid is returned from here.
so the same pid variable gives different values in parent and child.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a real `vfork` that's not just implemented in terms of `fork`, this program invokes serious undefined behavior. `printf` in the child process will modify the same `FILE` object (`stdout`) in the parent process's address space, possibly leaving it in a state that's not valid for the parent. In practice it may work, but if it does, that's a consequence of implementation details you cannot rely on not to change. The only operations that are safe to perform after `vfork` are `_exit` and the `exec` family of functions.

As for *how* it works (modulo the `printf` issue), `vfork` suspends the parent process until the child terminates, so when `vfork` returns in the parent, the child has already exited and the new return value is able to be stored at the same location the old one was stored in the child.

Comment: I have used _exit(1) for child.

if(pid==0)
    {
            printf("[CHILD] child id : %d\n" , pid);
            _exit(1);
    }

This is absolutely fine. only if you use exit(1) , it will close the stdout and cause undefined error/

Comment: Calling `printf` is also a problem. That modifies `stdout`, which will later be used in the parent. `vfork` is not in any modern standard, but the original definition (in SVID, if I'm remembering correctly) specified that calling anything but `_exit` or `exec` after `vfork` is UB.